# How to prevent rounding in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rounding

suppose if a variable has a float value, and if i re-assign the same variable with an another float value it will round the fractional part of the value with respect to the no of fractional part in first value, how can i prevent that
eg:

```
wav=10.456878798
print wav
wav=10.555546877796546
print wav
```

> ```
> 10.456878798
> 10.5555468778
> ```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. It is not clipping the output based on its history. It is simply always showing a fixed number of significant digits. Try `import math; p=3.14; print p; p=math.pi; print p`.

Comment: try wav=float(10.555546877796546)

Comment: @SyedMauzeRehan I tried `float()` and it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, so the I just checked it is not rounding off the value, it is just printing ti that way... use python shell and > wav (enter)

it shall print the right value. It's something with the print statement. No need to do a float() either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following and set the precision :

```
$ cat test.py
a = 10.456878798
print "{0:.2f}".format(a)
a = 10.555546877796546
print "{0:.15f}".format(a)
```

The above will print you :

```
$ python test.py
10.46
10.555546877796546
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with Python. See *print* statement prints 10 decimal places of a fraction even though it has more. Just check your variable in python shell, it shall give you the entire value.

```
>>> wav = 10.232483243243243
>>> print wav
10.2324832432
>>> wav
10.232483243243243
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but i am not sure it is with print, i already tried with sys.stdout.write, it is also printing the rounded value.

Comment: Nit: The "10" in your answer isn't quite accurate: the `print` statement (for Python version < 3.2) shows a value based on *12* significant figures.  Though it's really the internal conversion to `str` (the same conversion that occurs when you do `str(wav)`) that's responsible for the rounding to 12 significant figures.  The `print` statement does that conversion implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions provided worked. So I decided to search the Standard Library and found a very useful formula. In order to do so you need to import decimal from the standard library and define the precision of the fractional part as follow. This way you will have 28 digits in the fraction part!

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 28
```

after that in the python shell, you would find as follow:

```
Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)

Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y = 3.1415926535897932384626
y = "{:.6f}".format(y)
y = str(y)
y = y[:-2]
print(y)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Also, how is this any different from the existing answers, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29249205/5211833)?